# Manipulate an Array with Javascript

Tags: arrays, regex

I'm using the following script to validate a string.

```
var m;
var re = /([7]{1}[8,5]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ][0-9]{3}[ ][0-9]{3})[a-zA-Z0-9_.\- ]*([0-9]{6})/; // VW MQB
if ((m = re.exec(value)) !== null) {
 if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
   re.lastIndex++;
 }
   return m;
}
```

The result is an array. Now, I want to delete the spaces in all values. Futhermore I want to prepend one "0" (Zero) at the last value.
Is it possible without dissolve the array and afterwards to create an new array?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible without dissolve the array and afterwards to create an new array?

Sure, just use a loop:

```
var n;
for (n = 0; n < m.length; ++n) {
    m[n] = m[n].replace(/ /g, "");   // Remove spaces
}
m[m.length-1] = "0" + m[m.length-1]: // Add "0" before last entry
```